Can't "Select Flutter: New Project" on visual studio code using ubuntu "No matching results" message appears
following the link
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
I installed visual studio code on ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
then i Install Flutter following
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux/android?tab=later-start
instructions, at "Install the Flutter SDK" section I chose to install it using VS Code.
At the "Prompt VS Code to install Flutter" sections 1 to 4 seys:

Launch VS Code.
To open the Command Palette, press Control + Shift + P.
In the Command Palette, type flutter.
Select Flutter: New Project.

when i type "flutter" in the command palette it appears the message:
"No matching results"
the frustrating part is that when I run the "flutter doctor" function I have:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 6.5.0-28-generic, locale es_ES.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

I've already tried all kinds of things and it hasn't worked so far.
I have already installed flutter on a Windows PC and I have developed applications successfully, everything got complicated when I tried it in Ubuntu and I really need this working in Ubuntu
I thank you in advance to everyone who answers
trying to crate a flutter app using visual studio code and ubuntu

Can you make sure of the Flutter and dart extensions

Is the flutter  extension enabled for the current workspace?

the flutter and dart extensions are installed and enabled

It seems that when writing "Flutter: New Project" I missed adding the ">" character at the beginning, so what should really be written is ">Flutter: New Project". With this the topic is concluded.
